# Scrollview has lost the acceleration

Tags: android, gesture, android-scrollview

I made a XML of a fragment, composed by a Scrollview, but I don't know why it has lost the acceleration, when I lift my finger of the screen, the scrollview stops immediately.

The component com.mindorks.placeholderview.PlaceHolderView has a lot of items and the behaivour with this issue is horribly.

My fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAutomaticDarkGrey">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAutomaticLightGray"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAutomaticDarkGrey">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="32dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_prueba"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_prueba"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlMagicIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlLogo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorAutomaticDarkGrey"
            android:gravity="center">

            <net.lucode.hackware.magicindicator.MagicIndicator
                android:id="@+id/magic_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorAutomaticDarkGrey"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextMontserratRegularFont"
                android:theme="@style/TextMontserratRegularFont" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerSearchBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlMagicIndicator"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAutomaticWhite"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/search" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivSearch"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivFilter"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivSearch"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ivFilter">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etSearch"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@color/colorAutomaticWhite"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/search_here"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoFullscreen|flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:pointerIcon="none"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextMontserratRegularFont"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAutomaticUnfocusedGray"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAutomaticUnfocusedGray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_14sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivClear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/close" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFilter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAutomaticWhite"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/filter" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitleVideos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/containerSearchBar"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="@string/str_all_videos"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextMontserratRegularFont"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAutomaticUnfocusedGray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <com.mindorks.placeholderview.PlaceHolderView
            android:id="@+id/listPlaceHolderView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitleVideos"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="always" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDuration="1500"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorAutomaticRose"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:prompt="@string/str_en"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:splitMotionEvents="false"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:background="@color/colorAutomaticDarkGrey"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace ScrollView with [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

and use `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`

Comment: It has the same behaivor

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem by finding the view in the class (com.mindorks.placeholderview.PlaceHolderView) and declaring setter that Manza sais.

```
listPlaceHolderView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I didn't need to change the "ScrollView" layout to "NestedScrollView".